# Как перевести заданный текст в консольное приложение в С#

Tags: c#

Как  переписать текст в консольное приложение?

```
public class WaveFormat
{
    byte[] ByteSrcMas;
    BitArray BitSrcMas,BitDstMas;
    public int BpS;
    public int Size;
    public int Count;
    int Pas;
    public int Pass;
    public WaveFormat()
    {
    }
    public int ParseWaveFile(string file)
    {
        ByteSrcMas = File.ReadAllBytes(file); //считывание всего файла
        if ((ByteSrcMas[0] != 'R') || (ByteSrcMas[1] != 'I') || (ByteSrcMas[2] != 'F') || (ByteSrcMas[3] != 'F')) //проверка заголовка RIFF
            return 1;
        if ((ByteSrcMas[8] != 'W') || (ByteSrcMas[9] != 'A') || (ByteSrcMas[10] != 'V') || (ByteSrcMas[11] != 'E')) //проверка заголовка WAVE
            return 1;
        if ((ByteSrcMas[12] != 'f') || (ByteSrcMas[13] != 'm') || (ByteSrcMas[14] != 't') || (ByteSrcMas[15] != ' ')) //проверка заголовка fmt 
            return 1;
        byte[] mas = new byte[4]; //считывание размера заголовков
        mas[0] = ByteSrcMas[16];
        mas[1] = ByteSrcMas[17];
        mas[2] = ByteSrcMas[18];
        mas[3] = ByteSrcMas[19];
        int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(mas, 0);
        byte[] mas2 = new byte[2];
        mas2[0] = ByteSrcMas[20];
        mas2[1] = ByteSrcMas[21];
        int tag = BitConverter.ToInt16(mas2, 0);
        if (tag != 1)
            return 2;
        Count = 20 + 14;
        mas2[0] = ByteSrcMas[Count];
        mas2[1] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 1];
        BpS = BitConverter.ToInt16(mas2, 0);
        Count = Count + value - 16 + 2;
        if ((ByteSrcMas[Count] == 'f') && (ByteSrcMas[Count + 1] == 'a') && (ByteSrcMas[Count + 2] == 'c') && (ByteSrcMas[Count + 3] == 't'))
        {
            Count = Count + 3 + 1; //пропуск области fact
            mas[0] = ByteSrcMas[Count];
            mas[1] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 1];
            mas[2] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 2];
            mas[3] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 3];
            value = BitConverter.ToInt32(mas, 0);
            Count = Count + 3 + value + 1;
        }
        if ((ByteSrcMas[Count] != 'd') || (ByteSrcMas[Count + 1] != 'a') || (ByteSrcMas[Count + 2] != 't') || (ByteSrcMas[Count + 3] != 'a'))
            return 1;
        Count = Count + 3 + 1;
        mas[0] = ByteSrcMas[Count];
        mas[1] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 1];
        mas[2] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 2];
        mas[3] = ByteSrcMas[Count + 3];
        Size = BitConverter.ToInt32(mas, 0); //размер аудиоданных
        Count = Count + 3;
        BitSrcMas = new BitArray(ByteSrcMas);
        Pass = (Count * 8)+8;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен.

Comment: Он написан не в консольном приложении. Как переписать эту программу в режиме консольного приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Класс `WaveFormat` не привязан к какой-либо технологии, берите и используйте хоть в косольном, хоть в веб-приложении.

Comment: ок) он мне выдает ошибки))

Comment: 1) "ConsoleApplication1.WaveFormat.ByteArray" является "поле", но используется как "тип"

Comment: Помогите. Скиньте преобразованный текст. Неичего не получается. Голову уже сломала, как преобразовать. Он и так использовал класс WaveFormat. Не работает. Может ошибка допустила я. Но я его не вижу. При запуске одни ошибки.

Comment: Покажи полностью приложение в консольном виде.

Comment: пришлите почту скину туда. нет возможности выложить сюда

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано, данный класс не привязан к технологии и может быть легко мигрирован под консольное приложение - достаточно просто скопировать его в другой проект. В вашем случае вы его всего лишь неправильно используете, а именно:

```
ConsoleApplication1.WaveFormat.ByteArray
```

Откуда такое обращение к классу? В нем нет статических методов и свойств. Для использования необходимо создать объект и вызывать у него нужные методы:

```
var wave = new WaveFormat();
wave.НужныйМетод();
```

Comment: Я спасибо он и так загружал Wav файлы. Мне нужено этот кусок программы перебит в консольный режим! и он в строке BitSrcMas = new BitArray(ByteSrcMas); ругается на BitArray и пишет что там ошибка "ConsoleApplication1.WaveFormat.ByteArray" является "поле", но используется как "тип". Кто нибудь перебейти этот кусок проги в консольный режим!!!! чтоб работал!!! я уже над этим голову сломала и мое знание Visual С# иссякло.

Comment: Я вас не понимаю - что значит "перебить в консольный режим"? У меня эта чуда-прога работает в консоли и не выдает ошибок, чего вы вообще от нее хотите?

Comment: Использую такой код:

var f = new WaveFormat();
f.ParseWaveFile(@"C:\booze.wav");
Console.WriteLine(f.Count);

В результате выводит каунт... Как воспроизвести вашу проблему?